# How can I fix this situation i have an error on argument that expected

Tags: php, html, function, syntax

```
function calculate(){
    echo "Number of argument :" . func_get_args() ;
    echo "Argument index number 3 is" . func_get_arg(3);
    print_r(func_get_arg());
    $result = 0;
    foreach(func_get_arg() as $arg) :
        $result += $arg;
    end foreach;
    echo $result;

calculate(10, 20, 30, 1502);
```

How can I fix this situation i have an error on argument that expected on this function variable arguments list  ?

Comment: Replace `func_get_arg` by `func_get_args` where appropriate (lines 4 and 6)

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of PHP don't allow mismatches between the function parameter list and the argument list in the call. Instead of calling `func_get_args()` you use ellipsis in the argument list to allow unlimited arguments.

```
function calculate(...$args){
    echo "Number of argument :" . count($args) ;
    echo "Argument index number 3 is" . $args[3];
    print_r($args);
    $result = 0;
    foreach($args as $arg) :
        $result += $arg;
    end foreach;
    echo $result;
}
```